# Apache Camel on a JAXRS API?

Tags: apache-camel, jax-rs

Could anybody explain how Apache Camel is able to behave as a routing and mediation engine on a JAXRS API?

As far I've being reading about I've not been able to figure out what's it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider Apache Camel as a great integration framework. It doesn't provide functionality itself, but it makes easy to glue multiple services and protocols together.

Apache Camel can expose a REST endpoint using the  [CXFRS component](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html). This means it listens for a REST call on certain endpoint (URL). On invocation it doesn't invoke the implementing bean (service) itself, but executes a defined mediation route (invoke a route with its Exchange object).

It is very useful when you need to integrate multiple services or translate the call to other protocols. You can implement a REST service by a bean itself and it's ok until the bean provides some functionality or data itself. For integration you often need more flexibility to integrate multiple sources and protocols. Then Apache Camel can be much more practical tool.